# Spring Security Custom Authentication Filter and Authorization

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, filter, authorization

I've implemented a custom authentication filter, and it works great. I use an external identity provider and redirect to my originally requested URL after setting my session and adding my authentication object to my security context.

**Security Config**

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // this is needed to pass the authentication manager into our custom security filter
    @Bean
    @Override
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers("/admin/test").hasRole("METADATA_CURATORZ")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CustomSecurityFilter(authenticationManagerBean()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    }
}
```

**Filter logic**

For now, my custom filter (once identity is confirmed) simply hard codes a role:

```
SimpleGrantedAuthority myrole = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("METADATA_CURATORZ")
                return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(securityUser, null, [myrole])
```

That authentication object (returned above) is then added to my SecurityContext before redirecting to the desired endpoint:

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)`

**Controller Endpoint**

```
  @RequestMapping(path = '/admin/test', method = GET, produces = 'text/plain')
  String test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()

    String roles = auth.getAuthorities()
    return "roles: ${roles}"
  }
```

This endpoint then yields a response in the browser of:

> "roles: [METADATA_CURATORZ]"

Great. So my authentication and applying a role to my user is working great.

Now, if I uncomment this line from the security config:

`//.antMatchers("/admin/test").hasRole("METADATA_CURATORZ")`

I can no longer access that resource and get a 403 -- even though we've already proven the role was set.

This seems totally nonsensical and broken to me, but I'm no Spring Security expert.

I'm probably missing something very simple. Any ideas?

Some questions I have:

- Does my custom filter need to be placed before a specific built-in filter to ensure the authorization step occurs after that filter is executed?
- When in the request cycle is the antMatcher/hasRole check taking place?
- Do I need to change the order of what I am calling in my security configure chain, and how should I understand the config as I've currently written it? It's obviously not doing what I think it should be.

Comment: Did you solved this problem? Can you share a step by step guide for using custom roles with spring security.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Does my custom filter need to be placed before a specific built-in filter to ensure the authorization step occurs after that filter is executed?

Your filter **MUST** come before `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, because that is where authorization and authentication take place. This filter is one of the last to be invoked.

Now as to where the best place for your filter might be, that really depends. For example, you really want your filter to come before `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` because if not, unauthenticated users will always be "authenticated" with an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` by the time your filter is invoked.

You can check out the default order of filters in [`FilterComparator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterComparator.java). The `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` pretty much corresponds to what it is you're doing - and its placement in the order of filters gives you an idea of where you could put yours. In any case, there should be no issue with your filter's order.

> When in the request cycle is the antMatcher/hasRole check taking place?

All of this happens in `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, and more precisely, in its parent `AbstractSecurityInterceptor`:

```
protected InterceptorStatusToken beforeInvocation(Object object) {

    Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes = this.obtainSecurityMetadataSource()
            .getAttributes(object);

    if (attributes == null || attributes.isEmpty()) {
        ...
    }

    ...

    Authentication authenticated = authenticateIfRequired();

    // Attempt authorization
    try {
        this.accessDecisionManager.decide(authenticated, object, attributes);
    }
    catch (AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) {

        ...

        throw accessDeniedException;
    }
```

**Extra information:**
In essence, the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` has a `ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource` that contains a `Map<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>>`. At runtime, your request is checked against the `Map` to see if any `RequestMatcher` key is a match. If it is, a `Collection<ConfigAttribute>` is passed to the `AccessDecisionManager`, which ultimately either grants or denies access. The default `AccessDecisionManager` is `AffirmativeBased` and contains objects (usually a `WebExpressionVoter`) that process the collection of `ConfigAttribute` and via reflection invokes the `SpelExpression` that corresponds to your `"hasRole('METADATA_CURATORZ')"` against a `SecurityExpressionRoot` object that was initialized with your `Authentication`.

> Do I need to change the order of what I am calling in my security configure chain, and how should I understand the config as I've currently written it? It's obviously not doing what I think it should be.

No, there shouldn't be any issue with your filters. Just as a side note, in addition to what you have in your `configure(HttpSecurity http)` methods, the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you extend from has some defaults:

```
http
    .csrf().and()
    .addFilter(new WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter())
    .exceptionHandling().and()
    .headers().and()
    .sessionManagement().and()
    .securityContext().and()
    .requestCache().and()
    .anonymous().and()
    .servletApi().and()
    .apply(new DefaultLoginPageConfigurer<>()).and()
    .logout();
```

You can take a look at `HttpSecurity` if you want to see exactly what these do and what filters they add.

### THE PROBLEM

When you do the following:

```
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin/test").hasRole("METADATA_CURATORZ")
```

... the role that is searched for is `"ROLE_METADATA_CURATORZ"`. Why?
`ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer`'s static `hasRole(String role)` method ends up processing `"METADATA_CURATORZ"`:

```
if (role.startsWith("ROLE_")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "role should not start with 'ROLE_' since it is automatically inserted. Got '"
                        + role + "'");
    }
    return "hasRole('ROLE_" + role + "')";
}
```

So your authorization expression becomes `"hasRole('ROLE_METADATA_CURATORZ'"` and this ends up calling the method `hasRole('ROLE_METADATA_CURATORZ')` on `SecurityExpressionRoot`, which in turn searches for the role `ROLE_METADATA_CURATORZ` in the `Authentication`'s authorities.

### THE SOLUTION

Change

```
SimpleGrantedAuthority myrole = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("METADATA_CURATORZ");
```

to:

```
SimpleGrantedAuthority myrole = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_METADATA_CURATORZ");
```